# Couldn't able to pass the anchor tag id value through ng-click in Angular JS. Getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm a newbie in AngularJS please help me out to find the issue , code shown below ( html code part - 1 with js code part-2) is working perfectly in my browser and I'm getting the alert.

**Html Code**

```
<a  id={{data.id}} ng-click='onclickof("data")' class="item item-icon-left" >

               {{data.name}} + {{data.id}}
</a>
```

**Function defined on controller**

```
$scope.onclickof= function(idinput){
  alert(idinput);
  }
```

But  when I tried to pass the anchor tag id to my function its giving alert with '**undefined**' string.  Please check the code below.

**Html code which passing id of anchor tag.**

```
<a  id={{data.id}} ng-click='onclickof(this.id)' class="item item-icon-left" >

                {{data.name}} + {{data.id}}
  </a>
```

Can anyone help me to find out the issue .
Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `ng-click='onclickof(data.id)'`

You can also use your first example but without quotes like `ng-click='onclickof(data)'`

Comment: Glad to hear it would also help if you mark this as you answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will just have to this

```
ng-click='onclickof(data.id)'
```

'this.id' will not work because it is not under the $scope.

For more information regarding this please check:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: I do not think this has nothing to do with angular $scope by using keyword this it is more subject to JavaScript function scope and execution context